# how to take segment controller in orange and white color combination

Tags: ios, xib, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to implement UISegment controller in Orange and Gray color combination in view did load method.I had done the colors changes after selecting the segment controller.But I want by default it need to show orange and gray colors.
Any one please guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement one custom segmented controller with two button images.. Hopefully You can find custom segmented controllers code in stackoverflow or in github.

Comment: Thanks NHS.I;ll follow like this way.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will not easily possible with default `UISegmentControl`, here's a custom segment control for the same, [SVSegmentedControl](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/svsegmentedcontrol)

A sample segement examples (source https://github.com/samvermette/SVSegmentedControl/)

[image]

There's many ways to customize the control.